# How to keep screen OFF while charging (S3 and Note 2)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Don't know if all the Galaxy phones have this behaviour, but it sure is annoying.
I like to keep my phone plugged in until I need it, as there is no harm done. The battery won't get "overcharged" or anything, and I'll have 100% juice with me when I leave.

But both phones keep lighting up that they are done.
And it lights up the phone every few seconds, it's really, really annoying.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: Leaving it charge is actually bad for it. LiOn batteries do not like to be constantly topped up, also the tend to stay warm in this scenario and this is VERY bad for the device. Have you rooted? If so, you can turn this off with Wanam Xposed? http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries

Comment: @RossC: I thought li-ion stops at full charge. I left my older phones on juice too, same for my iPhone. The phone is not rooted (the wifi module is faulty, gotta love Samsung "quality".) So yeah. Waiting to return the phone third time (in weeks.) Other than that, I'll just get a ZeroLemon then.

Comment: even if it did, there's still the heat factor. Heat is a battery's worst enemy and leaving it charge for a long time has an inheret heating effect. It isn't terrible, but it definitely isn't the best. I've a few android devices and the 2 I used to charge overnight have a noticably worse battery life than the ones I just charge normally. The advice I've always been give is, don't let it run out fully, don't over charge it. The phones always tell you to plug in at 15% and to unplug when charged, usually for a reason!

Comment: @RossC: Xposed can disable this behaviour it turns out. | #Overcharge: There is no heat if you charge it up full, so I don't think leaving it on charger damages the battery. Heck, laptops have no issue that have been kept on AC for years.

Answer (score 2):

I too have not figured out the intermittent screen turn on problem but will address one other issued mentioned.

Lithium ion  batteries have internal circuitry which shuts the charging down when the battery is at 100%. Unless the electronics are bad, you cannot overcharge them. Leaving them discharged for long periods CAN harm them. You can get roughly 300 to 500 recharges, its best to not run it all the way down, recharge often, when not using it, the charges are cumulative, so a 30% discharged battery is best charged then, not when it runs down.

This can easily be verified at manufacturers web sites. Ive learned this from years of being involved in electronics and seeing the evolution of rechargables

Answer (score 1):

Try [Battery 100% Alarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appeteria.battery100alarm). It has an option for turning the screen off after 100% Battery Level Alarm rings.

Comment: Thanks. Will do. This is stupid though. "protect your phone battery". It will only drain if you play games on it, then indeed you damage your battery. Okay, waste a cycle in a few days with that. But otherwise, it will just stay on 100% and instead of damaging it, it will protect the battery. (Since, no charge cycle wasted while you have it on charger 24/7.)

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck Settings->Accessory->Dock->Desktop Home Screen Display

Comment: It was unticked. Only Dock Sound was ticked. :/ The screen lights up, and then goes dark. After a while it lights up again. Then down. And this goes on and on and on. :/

Answer (score 0):

The screen on my phone turns on when the battery is 100% charged... I would also like to be able to disable that feature but haven't found a method to yet.

Once I turn the screen off however, it does not come back on again while the battery is at 100%.  Presumably, if the phone went below 100% and/or started charging again it would go back up to 100% and the screen would turn on again, so something to check--if you use a charging cable instead of a dock--make sure the USB connector is not old or bad (i.e., intermittent).

If the USB connector doesn't make good contact then the phone's charging logic can be re-triggered and the screen will come back on.  You can see the effects of this yourself by plugging and unplugging the charger.  The display may come on briefly, turn off briefly, then turn back on again to say that it's fully charged, and a cheap USB cable that wears out can eventually cause this to happen repeatedly.

I don't think this is the issue you're having based on the symptoms described, but something to look at.  Another possibility would be a sub-standard charger and/or heavy processor usage on the phone that allows the battery to be charged but then discharged enough while it's still plugged in so that the phone thinks it needs to start charging again.  I'm not sure if that can actually happen or not, but if the phone thinks it's time to charge the battery again, and then it charges to 100% almost immediately, you will get another notification with the screen turning on.

Answer (score 0):

According to Samsung when the battery is fully charged it will notify you, that's what turns the light on. It keeps notifying you, annoying, but Samsung says it is normal and that there "is no feature to turn it off at this time."

I did find a partial solution.

1. I turned the volume down on the notifications, I can live without them. It's better than hearing them at night.
2. I took a picture with the camera lens covered. This gives a black screen. I then set the home and lock screens to us this black photo. This eliminated the bright blue screen.

   You can optionally turn the touch pad lights to not come on in settings, display touch pad lights. I can live without those as well.

   Then you can optionally, turn the clock off for the lock screen or make it the smallest size. This all cuts the light down dramatically when you are fully charged.
3. I then just turn the phone over.

This all yields a half baked solution I can live with.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings>>Developer Options (under System)>>Stay Awake (uncheck this)